# Get Pixmap out of Xlib

Tags: xlib, pixmap

I've been trying to find a way of grabbing video directly from an X window and got pointed to Xlib and the compositing extension.

So far, I've been able to listen to change events and grab a Pixmap with this code:

```cpp
#include <X11/Intrinsic.h>
#include <X11/extensions/Xcomposite.h>
#include <X11/extensions/Xdamage.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int br, base;
    Window win = 0x3400003;
    Display *dsp = XOpenDisplay(0);
    XCompositeQueryExtension(dsp, &base, &br);
    XDamageQueryExtension(dsp,&base, &br);


    cout << base << endl;

    Damage damage = XDamageCreate(dsp, win, XDamageReportRawRectangles);
    XCompositeRedirectWindow(dsp, win, CompositeRedirectAutomatic);

    XEvent ev;
    while(true) {
        XNextEvent(dsp, &ev);
        if(ev.type == base + XDamageNotify) {
            Pixmap pm = XCompositeNameWindowPixmap(dsp, win);
            XWindowAttributes attr;
            XGetWindowAttributes(dsp, win, &attr);
            XWriteBitmapFile(dsp, "test.bmp", pm, attr.width, attr.height, -1, -1);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    XCompositeUnredirectWindow(dsp, win, CompositeRedirectAutomatic);
    XDamageDestroy(dsp, damage);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem here is that the resulting bmp (created by XWriteBitmapFile) is black&white horribleness. Disregarding the fact that I don't want to write the data to file anyway, I am apparently doing something wrong in reading it.
I would love to convert the Pixmap to either a framebuffer in opengl or a binary blob in ram.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me on this.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Bitmaps" in X world refer to two-colored images. I guess [XWriteBitmapFile](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/utilities/XWriteBitmapFile.html) does internally GetImage request and transforms server pixmap to a bitmap. Note that file format is it's own 'X11 bitmap', not windows bitmap.

Use [XGetImage](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/graphics/XGetImage.html) function If you actually need image's binary blob.

Comment: Sorry to answer without trying it first, but it seems to me XGetImage always gets data directly from the screen. This would make it impossible for me to get an image of a hidden window, which is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: No, it always gets pixels from drawable, but in X "unviewable" (that is unmapped or overlapped by other windows) drawables usually don't store their content and there is no guarantee that you get pixels you want. You need to use Composite extension to always save window content

Comment: Okay, then I'll look into using my compositing manager for retrieving the data. If you could add the problem with hidden drawables to your answer for future reference that would be great. =)